# Horizontal align of section* in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I want the `section*` to be aligned with all the other entries in the table of contents.

I guess that `tocloft` is the package I need to achieve that, but at the moment I couldn't understand what is the command I need to use.

Besides, calling for `tocloft` removes the page breaks between the sections and chapters. How can I keep the page breaks in the default behaviour?

MWE

```latex
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,leqno,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
% zero indentaion for paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
First page of the document.

\tableofcontents{}

\listoffigures
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum, blah blah blah

\chapter{First chapter}
Dolor sit amet, blah blah blah
\section{Nothing important}
Text continues
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could change `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}` to `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textmd{Introduction}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too clear what you looking for. Because if you set the indent of unnumbered section heading to 0pt, this will influence the numbered section heading as well. If you only want that one single entry to have 0 indent, as commented by Mico, you could set it locally. However, there is a little bit confused because if the `Introduction` is a chapter, you should use `\chapter*{Introduction}` not `\section*{Introduction}`. And using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}`, you won't get the dotted style entry in the toc. Anyway, following is a method use `tocloft` to set the global indent for chapters and sections. To make the default pagebreak working you could use `titles` option when you call `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,leqno,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{2.3em}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
% zero indentaion for paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}
First page of the document.

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum, blah blah blah

\chapter{First chapter}
Dolor sit amet, blah blah blah
\section{Nothing important}
Text continues
\end{document}
```

[image]